# Logical operator And between two images

Tags: java

I have this method to a logical AND operation between two images , the result should be a third image with the parts in common, but it creates a blank image , why?

```
public BufferedImage Caland ( BufferedImage image1 , BufferedImage image2 , image3 BufferedImage , int height , int width ) {

        int argb1 , argb2 ;
        int a1, r1, g1 , b1 ;
        int a2, r2, g2 , b2 ;
        aand int , rand , Ghent, bAnd ;
        and int ;
        for (int y = 0; y < height ; y + +) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x + +) {
                argb1 image1.getRGB = (x, y ) ;
                argb2 image2.getRGB = (x, y ) ;

                a1 = ( argb1 >> 24 ) & 0xFF ;
                r1 = ( argb1 >> 16) & 0xFF ;
                g1 = ( argb1 >> 8 ) & 0xFF ;
                b1 = ( argb1 ) & 0xFF ;

                a2 = ( argb2 >> 24 ) & 0xFF ;
                r2 = ( argb2 >> 16) & 0xFF ;
                g2 = ( argb2 >> 8 ) & 0xFF ;
                b2 = ( argb2 ) & 0xFF ;

                aand = a1 & a2 ;
                rand = r1 & r2 ;
                Ghent & g1 = g2 ;
                bAnd = b1 & b2 ;
               
                and = ( aand << 24) & ( Rand << 16 ) & ( Ghent << 8 ) & aand ;
                image3.setRGB (x, y , and) ;
            }
        }
        return image3 ;
    }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: a logical 'And' between two images? the logical 'and' is basically 'if expression1 AND expression1'.
you mean you are trying to show two images over each other, or something similar?

Comment: If 'And'ing those two numbers gives a number greater than 255 then you will get blank image. Try checking the values after 'And' operation

Comment: @Nullpointer - How could ANDing two values that are 255 or smaller result in a number larger than 255??

Comment: @Stultuske - I'm pretty sure the OP means "bitwise AND".

Comment: Stella, it's hard to follow your logic through the code (without spending more time than I'd want looking at your problem).  Insert println statements through the code (or use a debugger) to examine intermediate values in your computation and see that they make sense and each is producing the expected result.

Comment: But I'm kind of thinking that in that last assignment to `and` you should be using bitwise OR instead of bitwise AND.

Comment: A _bitwise and_ between the respective RGBA components will not show you the parts in common. For instance if r1=5 and r2=10, the bitwise and is 0. If you are expecting 5, perhaps you should use _min(r1, r2)_?

Comment: Also your code is a little messed up, but I'm guessing it's a copy/paste or search/replace issue.

Comment: I have included various System.out and results of various operations is not always 255 then I would have to see something? 
It contains code errors due to the copy / paste. 
How can I improve this process of 'AND' bit by bit? 
thanks

Comment: I still can't understand what you are trying to do. Perhaps you should post an example of two input images and what you expect as an output.

Comment: For example, the contents of the slide 7 of this link https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CH0QFjAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Foscar.iitb.ac.in%2FOSCARPP%2FElectrical%2520Engineering%2FUploadedStoryboards%2FLogical%2520operations.ppt&ei=Tit7U9HpCa2Y0QWPlIDoDg&usg=AFQjCNGX93gBLj85BtTUkIN7Hl-pwYW4Hg&sig2=Ozadql0Jss4NX5_r9AJZOg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.d2k